# Java repeat String with str.repeat

Tags: java, string, eclipse, compilation, repeat

I have a problem with a fairly simple question in Java. To repeat a string, you can use str.repeat from Java 11. However I have the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method repeat(int) is undefined for the type String
```

The code is as follows:

```
String rep = "-";
rep = rep.repeat(4);
System.out.println(rep);
```

With a command-line compilation, no problem, but Eclipse is problematic, it uses

```
java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure you're using java 11 for the project your code is in?  Also, what version of eclipse are you using?  Older versions don't support newer versions of Java. Even if you've got eclipse pointing to the proper JDK, it might not have 11 available as a compiler compliance level.

Comment: try running this in eclipse: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.version"));`

Comment: Look at the 'Java Compiler' settings in the project Properties and make sure it is set to Java 11 or above. Look at the 'Java Build Path' in the Properties and make sure you are using a Java 11 or above JRE/JDK.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, these were the configuration files that eclipse generated, it was not using the right version of Java, despite the message displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

repeat is **Java 11** keyword. You are trying to use repeat from a lower version than Java 11.

modify the code with for loop as below.

```
 String rep = "";
 for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
    rep += "-";
 }
 System.out.println(rep);
```